# Get the tag name of a xml file

Tags: xml, vba

Since one tag consist of numbers and changes each time I want to read it, but this code does not work and i get an error at StrMyXml.nodeName (invalid identifier).
Currently my code is this:

```
Sub Create_XSD()
   Dim StrMyXml As String, MyMap As XmlMap
   Dim StrMySchema As String
   Dim tempString As String
   StrMyXml = "<Translate>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<Alarms>"
   tempString = StrMyXml.nodeName
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<" & tempString & ">"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<Nummer>tempString</Nummer>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<Nummer Diagnosename DE>tempString & Text</Nummer Diagnosename DE>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<Nummer Diagnosename EN>tempString & Text</Nummer Diagnosename EN>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "</" & tempString & ">"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "</Alarms>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "<Alarms></Alarms>"
   StrMyXml = StrMyXml & "</Translate>"
   ' Turn off async loading.
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ' Add the string to the XmlMaps collection.
   Set MyMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(StrMyXml)
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   ' Create an empty file and output the schema.
   StrMySchema = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).Schemas(1).XML
   Open "D:\Users\F512\Desktop\MySchema.xsd" For Output As #1
   Print #1, StrMySchema
   Close #1
End Sub
```

Every help is appreciated!

Laurenz

Comment: Your question isn't that specific... please clarify exactly what you are asking

Comment: I want to read  a tag like Translate or Alarm (check above code).

Comment: Do you have any external libraries referenced?  When I run it I get an error on `tempString = StrMyXml.nodeName` of "Invalid qualifier" not identifier.  StrMyXml is a string, and strings don't have a `nodename` property.

Comment: I'm assuming `tempString = StrMyXml.nodeName` is a typo - where did you intend to get the tag number you want to use?

Comment: As you can probably see its my first time using vba. I read this site before: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753759(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Check the help documentation for the XmlMap object.  Click the cursor into it and hit F1 - It doesnt look like it has a NodeName property either.  It looks like it's for adding an XML map to a worksheet, or exporting from one.  I think it's explained why that code is erroring out, but it's still not clear what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dimensioned StrMyXml as a String:

`Dim StrMyXml As String`

But then you try:

`tempString = StrMyXml.nodeName`

This does not work because Strings do not have such a property.

Answer (score 0):

You have dimensioned StrMyXml as a String:

```
Dim StrMyXml As String
```

But then you try:

```
tempString = StrMyXml.nodeName
```

This does not work because Strings do not have such a property.